# winrt/c++: await result from dispatched task

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, async-await, winrt-async

I want to dispatch a job to the UI thread, then wait for the result and use it from another thread. Like this, but co_await does not work inside the lambda:

```
dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, [&]() {
    auto res = co_await mStoreContext.RequestPurchaseAsync(L"");
});
```

Or even waiting for the whole RunAsync operation, if I could get my result out from it

Comment: The more idiomatic way would be `co_await resume_foreground(dispatcher); auto res = co_await mStoreContext.RequestPurchaseAsync(L""); co_await resume_background(); use_result(res);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `void` can not be used as a return value from a coroutine (I can be if you use my  [my library](https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp)).

try returning a `std::future<void>` instead:

```
dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, [&]() -> std::future<void> {
    auto res = co_await mStoreContext.RequestPurchaseAsync(L"");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. even better would be a way to get the result out of the complete runasync block, but this works fine

Comment: This is dangerous because of the reference capture. The caller cannot return until it is sure the lambda has finished running.